# How do I access Git User’s Manual[1] using the terminal?

Tags: git, manpage

In the man page of git, there is a line which says:

```
See gittutorial(7) to get started, then see giteveryday(7) for a useful minimum set of commands.
The Git User’s Manual[1] has a more in-depth introduction.
```

How do I see the "The Git User's Manual[1]" from the terminal it self, instead of looking it up on the internet.

Comment: In which environment are you using git? Linux, windows?

Comment: I am using it in Linux.

Comment: The spelling on that note is not very helpful, but on Linux `locate` is a first resort, you can locate files with e.g. `locate user-manual.html` which on my install finds that user manual, and only that user manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[1]` part from `Git User’s Manual[1]` says it is a note.

Read until the end of the manual page (press the space bar to jump one page below) to go to the `NOTES` sections.

The first note is:

```
NOTES
    1. Git User’s Manual
       git-htmldocs/user-manual.html
```

`git-htmldocs/user-manual.html` is not a valid URL and it doesn't mean anything to me.

But the first section of `man git` (where you extracted the fragment you posted in the question) also says:

> A formatted and hyperlinked copy of the latest Git documentation can be viewed at https://git.github.io/htmldocs/git.html.

At https://git.github.io/htmldocs/git.html there is the same documentation as HTML and the [Git User's Manual](https://git.github.io/htmldocs/user-manual.html) link in this documentation points to: https://git.github.io/htmldocs/user-manual.html

---

You can also read the Git documentation on its website: https://git-scm.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

For example, for the command, `git clone <repo>`, you can either use:

$ man git-clone

or:

$ git help clone

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is asking. "The Git User's Manual[1]" looks like it should link somewhere. That's what OP is looking for.

Comment: That's for a specific command, I know that.
What I want to know is, when it says "see gittutorial(7)", I can see it using `$man gittutorial`, but how do I see `The Git User's Manual[1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of `man git` there are some reference links. The footnote number after "The Git User's Manual" should correspond to one of those links. On my machine I see

```
1. Git User’s Manual
   file:///usr/share/doc/git-doc/user-manual.html
```

So on my machine I can view `/usr/share/doc/git-doc/user-manual.html`. You can use a CLI browser like [links](http://links.twibright.com/) to simplify reading the HTML:

```
links /usr/share/doc/git-doc/user-manual.html
```

**Edit:** On my machine that file doesn't actually exist, and I don't see an Arch Linux package providing it. Hopefully the Git documentation on your machine is complete.

If your documentation is also missing and you don't mind hitting the network you can browse the User's Manual from Git's website, e.g.:

```
links https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual.html
```

Comment: The main thing that needed to be explained here was "a number in brackets means a footnote". They're not usually found in man pages, but it's a rule that applies to plain text documents in general. (Assuming we all understand that `[]` are brackets and `()` are parentheses)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley That makes so much sense now.
The file actually doesn't on my machine too. Looks like I have to use the one on the net.

Answer (score 1):

The Git User's Manual is a part of `git` itself. It can be accessed by cloning the `git` repository hosted at kernel.org.

The file you are looking for is [Documentation/user-manual.txt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/user-manual.txt). To access it in the terminal, clone one of these:

```
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/git/git.git
```

You can also clone just the docs without the rest of git from the `git-htmldocs` repository listed [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/). These include both the asciidoctor source and the rendered HTML.

Note that for browsing with just a web browser, the content is published [here](https://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html).

Answer (score 0):

The git user manual may be downloaded in txt format, here is its location:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/user-manual.txt

It can be downloaded using `wget` or `curl` commands.

Then it can be read using `less`, or perhaps a combination of `cat` and `grep`

Example:

```
## read the first 150 lines of chapter 'Exploring Git history'
cat user-manual.txt | grep "Exploring Git history" -A 150
```

Answer (score 0):

That answer is combination of already present ones plus explanation how to add file if it is not available locally.

When I run `man git` on my Linux, it has a phrase too:

> The Git User’s Manual[1]

It looks like a footnote and indeed near the the end of man page I see:

> ```
>     1. Git User’s Manual
>        file:///usr/share/doc/git/html/user-manual.html
> ```

However the file is absent:

```
$ ls /usr/share/doc/git/html/user-manual.html
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/doc/git/html/user-manual.html': No such file or directory
```

I was not able to find package to add it via `apt-get install` (during the search I've found that Q&A). To add it I used:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/htmldocs.git
```

The file is `user-manual.html` in `htmldocs` folder, I copied it

```
sudo mkdir --parents /usr/share/doc/git/html
sudo cp htmldocs/user-manual.html /usr/share/doc/git/html
```

Then one open it via web browser, e.g. as suggested in another answer with:

```
links /usr/share/doc/git/html/user-manual.html
```

(after `sudo apt-get install links` as mainstream Linux distros do not have it installed by default).